# rename enviromental variables from linking dockers

Tags: linux, variables, docker

When i create a link in docker environment variables in docker are automatically set but the names are not as i want them to be.
ex: 
a link called applink will result in

```
APPLINK_NAME=/app2/applink
APPLINK_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.4
APPLINK_PORT_80_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.4:80
APPLINK_PORT_80_TCP_PROTO=tcp
APPLINK_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.4:80
```

as environment variables i don't mind the naming schema but i do mind that the addr is name `"APPLINK_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR"` consists of the number 80 which is the port number is there anyway i can change the naming schema to skip the port number?
or create additional variables with a script with the same values but skipping the port number?

alternatively can i create a script to tokenize `APPLINK_PORT` into `CONNECTION_TYPE` , `IP_ADDR`, `PORT`

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't change the naming scheme (unless you were to modify the Docker code itself).  If the names...bother you?...you can certainly assign them to new variables in your start scripts:

```
APPLINK_TCP_ADDR=$APPLINK_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR
```

But I I'm not sure this would get you anything.

Comment: "declare -x APPLINK_TCP_ADDR=$APPLINK_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR" would work, i just want to be able to know the environment variable's name without needing to enter the container and manually look for it i wanna create scripts to publish the variables